# Gradle task: how to wait for the file operation to complete

Tags: file-io, gradle, groovy, unzip

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Copy archive (zip) from buildscript dependencies to the temp directory
2. Unzip archive to another directory within `build`

Here's task to copy archive (works)

```
task copyTpcds(type: Copy) {  
    file('build/zip').mkdirs()
    from buildscript.configurations.classpath
    include 'tpcds*'
    into 'build/zip'
}
```

And the task to unzip and then delete archive

```
task extractTpcds(type: Copy) {  
    def names = new FileNameFinder().getFileNames('build/zip', 'tpcds*')
    def outDir = file('build/cmd/tpcds')
    outDir.mkdirs() // make sure the directory exists
    from zipTree(file(names[0])) // generates error when 
    into outDir
    // now remove copied zip file
    //zipFile.delete() // deletes file before the extractions completes?
}
```

Here are few scenarios:

1. If I put both tasks into `build.gradle` and try to run anything, even just `gradle tasks` then I get this error: `Neither path nor baseDir may be null or empty string. path='null' basedir='C:\dev\code\td\pdo\tpcds-tpg'` from this code in the task #2: `file(names[0])`
2. If I comment out code in the 2nd task, 1st task would run and copy zip file to `build/zip`
3. Now I can uncomment code in the 2nd task (except deletion) and execute `gradle extractTpcds` it will run and extract the archive

So it seems to me that

1. File operations are evaluated across all tasks regardless of which tasks is executed
2. If I have a code that copies the file with some follow up code that tries to operate on the file being copied then  that code will not wait for copy process to complete and will fail because file is not there yet

I'm at loss on how to deal with this and would greatly appreciate your suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me, using Gradle 2.12 (and assuming that the zip file resides in `files`):

```
buildscript {
    configurations {
        classpath
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath files("files/tpcds.zip")
    }
}

def copyFiles = { ->
    ant.mkdir(dir: "build/zip")
    buildscript.configurations.classpath.each { def thisFile ->
        if (thisFile.name ==~ /tpcds.*/) {
            ant.copy(file: thisFile.absolutePath, todir: "build/zip")
        }
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == "extractTpcds") {
        copyFiles()
    }
}

task copyTpcds << {  
    copyFiles()
}

task extractTpcds(type: Copy) {  
    def names = new FileNameFinder().getFileNames('build/zip', 'tpcds*')
    def outDir = file('build/cmd/tpcds')
    outDir.mkdirs() // make sure the directory exists
    from zipTree(file(names[0])) // generates error when 
    into outDir
    // now remove copied zip file
    //zipFile.delete() // deletes file before the extractions completes?
}
```

An issue with the original involves an impedance mismatch vis-a-vis the ICE rule: Initialization phase, Configuration phase, and Execution phase. In particular, the specification of the Copy task is in Configuration phase; typically, task dependencies are enforced (e.g. `dependsOn`) during the Execution phase. The `extractTpcds` task has a dependency on other code during the *Configuration phase*.

In my example, there are are 2 cases:

- `gradle copyTpcds` will call the `copyFiles` method during Execution phase. The `<<` means "do this stuff last [during the Execution phase]".
- `gradle tasks` will trigger the code in `whenTaskAdded`, during Configuration phase, and call `copyFiles`. Similarly for `gradle extractTpcds`

An alternative to this is simply to use the AntBuilder in both tasks, and avoid `Type: Copy` completely, as shown here:

```
buildscript {
    configurations {
        classpath
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath files("files/tpcds.zip")
    }
}

task copyTpcds << {  
    ant.mkdir(dir: "build/zip")
    buildscript.configurations.classpath.each { def thisFile ->
        if (thisFile.name ==~ /tpcds.*/) {
            ant.copy(file: thisFile.absolutePath, todir: "build/zip")
        }
    }
}

task extractTpcds(dependsOn: 'copyTpcds') << {  
    def outDir = "build/cmd/tpcds"
    ant.mkdir(dir: outDir)
    def names = new FileNameFinder().getFileNames('build/zip', 'tpcds*')
    names.eachWithIndex { zipFile, index ->
        if (index == 0) {
            ant.unzip(src: zipFile, dest: outDir)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great, thanks Michael! For the completion can you please give an example of using Ant to unzip?

Comment: OK, I have added the second example ... note that it unzips the first zip file, but can easily be changed as needed.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work, but why do you need to delete the zip? chaining the tasks with dependsOn means you only need to run the second task and the copyTpcds will automatically run unless the inputs or outputs have changed (deleted)

```
task extractTpcds(type: Copy) {

    dependsOn(copyTpcds) //make this execute after

    def names = new FileNameFinder().getFileNames('build/zip', 'tpcds*')
    def outDir = file('build/cmd/tpcds')
    outDir.mkdirs() // make sure the directory exists
    from zipTree(file(names[0])) // generates error when 
    into outDir
    // now remove copied zip file
    doLast { zipFile.delete() }// deletes file after the extractions completes
}
```

Comment: This does not work. Like I said - it looks like regardless of the task you are trying to run all the variables including inline e.g. names[0] are evaluated right away across entire build.gradle. So to stress the point if I try to run seemingly unrelated task such as `gradle tasks` or `gradle clean` gradle will exit with `Neither path nor baseDir may be null or empty string. path='null'` error

Comment: That is unless zip file is present in build/zip directory per my example

Comment: Michael Ester provides an explanation why this will not work in his answer